# How to reference by a field other than id?

Tags: react-admin

I have a `<ReferenceField />` which needs to link using a field other than the `id` on the referred record.

```jsx
<ReferenceField source="provider_id" reference="provider" link="show">
  <TextField source="display_name" />
</ReferenceField>
```

The field on the current record is `provider_id`, but in the provider table the column I need is called `short_id` not `id`, which is different.

Is this possible in React Admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround using `<ReferenceManyField />`:

```jsx
<ReferenceManyField
  source="provider_id"
  target="short_id"
  reference="provider"
>
  <SingleFieldList>
    <TextField source="display_name" />
  </SingleFieldList>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

Comment: You might also want to take a look at ReferenceOneField: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceOneField.html